# Is there a way to set up a job scheduler to run a Jupyter Notebook with the input code hidden through JupyterLab Real-Time Collaboration?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab, jupyterhub

I am setting up a JupyterHub server and I would like to be able to do the following three things:

1. Enable JupyterLab Real-Time collaboration: https://jupyterlab-realtime-collaboration.readthedocs.io/en/latest/
2. Set up some type of job scheduler in JupyterLab (such as https://pypi.org/project/jupyterlab-scheduler/ or https://jupyter-scheduler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users/index.html#installation) to run my Jupyter Notebook nightly and output as HTML
3. Have the input code hidden from the resulting HTML file generated by the scheduler.

I am able to get either JupyterLab Real-Time collaboration (#1) and Jupyter Scheduler (#2) working together without the input code being hidden (#3), or I can get JupyterLab Real-Time collaboration (#1) working with the input code being hidden by the generated HTML (#3) but this seems to break the job scheduler.

Is there any way to get all three of these features working at the same time? Is there some other package or extension I can use to do this?

Comment: Are you using `jupyterlab-scheduler` or [`jupyter-scheduler`](https://github.com/jupyter-server/jupyter-scheduler/)? Both work in JupyterLab, the latter is maintained in within Jupyter Project. I think that it may be worth raising an issue directly with the scheduler extension, in case of jupyter-scheduler there already appears to be one on regarding RTC: https://github.com/jupyter-server/jupyter-scheduler/issues/429

Comment: Ah I see, I guess that explains why I couldn't get it working. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to use a bit of a work-around but got everything set up in the end using the following workflow:

1. Updated jupyter and all related packages/extensions
2. Enabled JupyterLab Real-time Collaboration
3. Downloaded the jupyter-scheduler extension
4. Created the python script "generate_report.ipynb" to convert my Jupyter Notebook to HTML with the "--no-input" flag using the command: jupyter nbconvert --to html --no-input report_results.ipynb
5. Used the jupyter-scheduler extension to set up a job to run the "generate_report.ipynb" script which executes the nbconvert command and produces the desired output.

Answer (score -1):

JupyterLab Real-Time Collaboration, a job scheduler for running Jupyter Notebooks, and automatically hiding input code in the generated HTML. These functionalities often required separate tools and extensions.
To achieve all three features, you may need to combine different solutions and extensions, and possibly write custom scripts or workflows. The exact compatibility between different extensions and tools can vary, so it may require some experimentation to get them working together seamlessly.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. Please only respond to questions with a valid answer.